# Exporting CSV file is not woking with double quotes value

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview, when I'm exporting this grid to csv format if the table contains double quotes the value data are not shown after the double quotes.(export contains value upto double but not after double quotes).If i remove the double quotes it is working correctly.

Comment: Whats you question now?

Comment: how are you viewing the data after export, in Excel? can you download the file again and before opening in excel open the file in Notepad. Do you get the same result?

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape your the double quote with another double quote

```
"value",""quoted value""
```

You could try using [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper) instead of implementing it yourself. It should handle quotes correctly.